# Python: Pivot Table/group by specific conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm trying to change structure of my data from text file(.txt) which data look like this:

```
:1:A
:2:B
:3:C
:1:D
:2:E
:3:F
:4:G
:1:H
:3:I
:4:J
```

And I would like to transform them into this format (like pivot-table in excel which column name is character between ":" and each group always start with :1:)

```
Group   :1: :2: :3: :4:
1        A   B   C
2        D   E   F   G
3        H       I   J
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
# Reading text file (assuming stored in CSV format, you can also use pd.read_fwf)
df = pd.read_csv('SO.csv', header=None)

# Splitting data into two columns
ndf = df.iloc[:, 0].str.split(':', expand=True).iloc[:, 1:]

# Grouping and creating a dataframe. Later dropping NaNs
res = ndf.groupby(1)[2].apply(pd.DataFrame).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))

# Post processing (optional)
res.columns = [':' + ndf[1].unique()[i] + ':' for i in range(ndf[1].nunique())]
res.index.name = 'Group'
res.index = range(1, res.shape[0] + 1)
res

Group   :1: :2: :3: :4:
1        A   B   C
2        D   E   F   G
3        H       I   J
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I tried to solve this problem for few days.

Answer (score 1):

First create DataFrame by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with `header=None`, because no header in file:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u""":1:A
:2:B
:3:C
:1:D
:2:E
:3:F
:4:G
:1:H
:3:I
:4:J"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=None)
print (df)
      0
0  :1:A
1  :2:B
2  :3:C
3  :1:D
4  :2:E
5  :3:F
6  :4:G
7  :1:H
8  :3:I
9  :4:J
```

Extract original column by [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html), then remove traling `:` by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) values to 2 new columns. Then create groups by compare with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==` by string `0` with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), create MultiIndex by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and last reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df[['a','b']] = df.pop(0).str.strip(':').str.split(':', expand=True)
df1 = df.set_index([df['a'].eq('1').cumsum(), 'a'])['b'].unstack(fill_value='')
print (df1)
a  1  2  3  4
a            
1  A  B  C   
2  D  E  F  G
3  H     I  J
```

Answer (score 0):

## Another way to do this:

```
#read the file
with open("t.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
#Create a dictionary and read each line from file to keep the column names (ex, :1:) as keys and rows(ex, A) as values in dictionary.
my_dict={}
for v in content:
    key = v.rstrip(':')[0:3] # take the value ':1:'
    value = v.rstrip(':')[3] # take value 'A'
    my_dict.setdefault(key,[]).append(value) 
#convert dictionary to dataframe and transpose it
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict,orient='index').transpose()
df
```

## The output will be looking like this:

```
   :1: :2: :3: :4:
0   A   B   C   G
1   D   E   F   J
2   H  None I  None
```